# How to access Shiny-Server with Amazon using a UDP protocol

Tags: amazon-web-services, tcp, shiny, udp, shiny-server

### Main Issue

I have setup a shiny-server on amazon lightsail on TCP port 3838. I am having latency issues and would like to try a UDP protocol instead. However, when I specify the port as UDP I can no longer access the shiny app from the web. How do I use AWS and Shiny-Server to host an application using UDP protocol?

### Details

I have tried from my laptop at home and a desktop computer at work. I have changed the protocol using the AWS GUI according to https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/overview/article/understanding-firewall-and-port-mappings-in-amazon-lightsail and in `/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf` I have

```
server {
    listen 3838;
    location /Game {
        app_dir /srv/shiny-server/Game;
```

When the protocol is TCP, I can just go to `http://my_ip:3838/Game` in my browser and access the application. I can also access the application when I change shiny.conf to listen on port 80 (TCP for http) and login to that page. When the protocol us UDP for a port, I cannot access the application.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: are you streaming movies or something. If you're having latency issues then launch your AWS on server close to you, or use google cloud

Comment: I am not streaming movies, I am hosting an R+Shiny application using shiny-server-pro. The AWS instance is in Oregon and I am in CA.

Comment: im sure we can help you once, you provide some example

Answer (score 0):

Althought possible, a UDP solution would require significant server-side programming. I would currently avoid this approach.